# Uploading multiple images is only sending one item .net core using ajax

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-core

I can't figure out why only one item is getting passed to the controller. Everything works as expected except if multiple files are selected it only takes the first file.

```
$("#photoSubmit").click(function () {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var imageDescriptions = [];

    // Collect all descriptions
    $("#image-list .list-images .list-itm").each(function () {
        var description = $(this).find("textarea").val();
        imageDescriptions.push(description);
    });

    // Iterate through file inputs and match each file with the respective description
    $("#frmUpload input[type='file']").each(function (index) {
        var fileInput = this;
        var description = imageDescriptions[index] || ""; 

        if (fileInput.files.length > 0) {
            formData.append("Photos[" + index + "].Image", fileInput.files[0]);
            formData.append("Photos[" + index + "].Description", description);
            formData.append("Photos[" + index + "].UserId", $("#u-id").val());
        }
    });

    formData.forEach(function (value, key) {
        console.log(key, value);
    });

    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: 'post',
        data: formData,

        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "html",
        url: "/User/Photo/AddPhoto",
        success: function (partialView) {
            // Handle the response here
        },
        error: function (partialView) {
            // Handle errors here
        }
    });
});
```

'''

Comment: Send your backend code(The method parameter or where it getting the images)

Comment: You append first file only to formData. that may be the issue.  this is the point "fileInput.files[0]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have `fileInput.files[0]` which only takes the first file from the file input. you could try below code which will help you to send multiple file:

```
$("#frmUpload input[type='file']").each(function (index) {
    var fileInput = this;
    var description = imageDescriptions[index] || ""; 

    // Loop through all selected files, not just the first one
    for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
        formData.append("Photos[" + index + "].Image", fileInput.files[i]);
        formData.append("Photos[" + index + "].Description", description);
        formData.append("Photos[" + index + "].UserId", $("#u-id").val());
    }
});
```

Also, there's an issue with your debug logging; `formData.forEach` is not a valid method as `FormData` does not have a `forEach` method. If you want to see the contents of the `formData`, you can iterate through it using `for...of`:

```
for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(key, value);
}
```

Make sure each file should have a unique key in the `formData` if they are to be identified separately on the server-side.check your backend is also correctly set up to handle multiple files being uploaded with the same key pattern (`Photos[index].Image`, `Photos[index].Description`). It should be able to differentiate between different files and their descriptions based on the index.